# There is no overloaded method "Rotate" with these parameters (array of points)

Tags: .net, arrays, methods, parameters, delphi-prism

I have a method called Rotate and I am calling it from another method as follows:

Rotate method as defined:

```
method TMakerGraphic.Rotate(var pts:array of Point; pcnt,xc,yc:integer);
```

Calling it from another method as follows:

```
method TMakerLine.GetDynamicBounds(var r:Rectangle);
var
  pts:array[1..2] of Point;
  midx,midy:integer;
begin
  with bounds do
  begin    
    pts[1].x := left;
    pts[1].y := top;
    pts[2].x := right;
    pts[2].y := bottom;

    if Active then
    begin
      r := bounds;
      with r do
      begin
        midx := ((right - left) div 2) + left;
        midy := ((bottom - top) div 2) + top;
      end;
      Rotate(var pts,2,midx,midy);    <<<<============= Here is where it raises the error
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It raises an error, "There is no overloaded method 'Rotate' with these parameters." I checked to make sure the parameters and method calls were correct and I think they are, but it is raising this error. I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because the `array of Point` type is a Unbound array and the `array[1..2] of Point` is a Bound array, so you are passing different types, to fix the issue declare the `pts` variable as a `array of Point` and then using `New` you can set the size of the array.

Check this sample

```
var
  pts:array of Point;
  midx,midy:integer;
begin
  with bounds do
  begin    
    pts:= New Point[2];
    pts[0].x := left;
    pts[0].y := top;
    pts[1].x := right;
    pts[1].y := bottom;
```

Comment: @ RRUZ , Fantastic. Works great. Thank you, but I do have a quick question. By creating new points within methods that will be called pretty frequently like 100 times a second maybe, are you going to run out or leak memory. I understand it is a local variable and thus gets destroyed everytime the program leaves the method.

Comment: The garbage collector of .Net will handle the  memory release for you, so don't worry about that